# iOS iTunes application link does not work

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, itunes

Every iOS application has its App Store link, which should redirect you to the App Store on iOS devices.

The link looks as follows:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/APP_NAME/APP_ID?mt=8

My application link (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/storyvine/id929186649?mt=8) works on desktop browser, but gives me an error on iOS device:

> iOS Update Required
>   
>   To view this story, you must update to the latest version of iOS.

However, my iOS version is already the latest one (currently 10.3.3).

[image: Screenshot from iOS device]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application's name and therefore, the URL starts with the name "Story".

As a side effect of this, the soon-to-be-updated App Store thinks that it's referring to an [App Store application story](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2017/06/apple-unveils-all-new-app-store/?imgid=1496428570321) (which is only included in iOS 11 and above) and not an actual App Store app. You should remove the application's name from the link, so it becomes:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id929186649?mt=8

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I know there is a new version available in iOS 11, however there are many application links that work as expected, e.g., https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tumblr/id305343404?mt=8. So I don't really understand, why mine isn't.

Comment: How did you get your app link?

Comment: https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/en-us/details/929186649?country=us&mediaType=ios_apps&term=storyvine

Comment: The app name must do something with this, as its name contains "story" and that may misdirect the store.

Comment: That would be weird. The URL was working before and stopped working only couple of days ago.